# images on iOS app causes multicolored lines through images

Tags: ios, png

I was hoping that someone could enlighten me on what this error means:: ImageIO: PNG IDAT: CRC error

It causes some images to show up as a bunch of multicolored lines and not the image as well as puts either a thick black solid line through the app or a bunch of multicolored lines.

The images are png's. I am not experienced with images. My design guy sent me these and he's not sure what's causing that because his experience is with websites and not iOS apps.

I also didn't not find too much on this online. My guess is that the images are corrupted.

Comment: The images are okay or they are not. Check with `pngcheck` or a similar tool. And if it's not the images then it is your drawing code.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I just had to go to build setting and change Compress PNG Files to NO instead of YES.